# Python 2 __missing__ method

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x, dictionary-missing

I wrote a very simple program to subclass a dictionary. I wanted to try the `__missing__` method in python.
After some research i found out that in Python 2 it's available in `defaultdict`. ( In python 3 we use collections.UserDict though..)
The `__getitem__` is the on responsible for calling the `__missing__` method if the key isn't found.

When i implement `__getitem__` in the following program i get a key error, but when i implement without it, i get the desired value.

```
import collections
class DictSubclass(collections.defaultdict):

    def __init__(self,dic):
        if dic is None:
            self.data = None
        else:
            self.data = dic

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.data[key] = value

    ########################
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.data[key]
    ########################

    def __missing__(self,key):
        self.data[key] = None

dic = {'a':4,'b':10}
d1 = DictSubclass(dic)
d2 = DictSubclass(None)    
print  d1[2]
```

I thought i needed to implement `__getitem__` since it's responsible for calling `__missing__`. I understand that the class definition of defaultdict has a `__getitem__` method. But even so, say i wanted to write my own `__getitem__`, how would i do it?

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that you can simplify the body of your init method to a single line: `self.data = dic`. Your current implementation is redundant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `dict` type will *always* try to call `__missing__`. All that `defaultdict` does is provide an implementation; if you are providing your own `__missing__` method you don't have to subclass `defaultdict` at all.

See the [`dict` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> **`d[key]`**
> Return the item of *d* with key *key*. Raises a `KeyError` if *key* is not in the map.
>
> If a subclass of dict defines a method `__missing__()` and *key* is not present, the `d[key]` operation calls that method with the key *key* as argument. The `d[key]` operation then returns or raises whatever is returned or raised by the `__missing__(key)` call. No other operations or methods invoke `__missing__()`.

However, you need to *leave the default `__getitem__` method in place*, or at least call it. If you override `dict.__getitem__` with your own version and not call the base implementation, `__missing__` is never called.

You could call `__missing__` from your own implementation:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key not in self.data:
        return self.__missing__(key)
    return self.data[key]
```

or you could call the original implementation:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key not in self.data:
        return super(DictSubclass , self).__getitem__(key)
    return self.data[key]
```

In Python 2, you can just subclass [`UserDict.UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#UserDict.UserDict):

```
from UserDict import UserDict

class DictSubclass(UserDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self.data[key] = None
```