# Grokking `__missing__`

Tags: python

I encounter an example of 'class' when learning about `str.format_map()`
([Python String format_map()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format_map))

```
class Coordinate(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key
```

Try arguments:

```
In [25]: Coordinate(x='6')
Out[25]: {'x': '6'}

In [26]:  Coordinate(x='6', y='7')
Out[26]: {'x': '6', 'y': '7'}
```

The hard part to understand is that neither`x=6` is a `dict` nor `{'x': '6'}` a key.

In official documentation, it specifies:

> `object.__missing__(self, key)`
> Called by `dict.__getitem__()` to implement `self[key]` for dict subclasses when key is not in the dictionary.

It's even more difficult than the previous sample code.
There are also good answers here.

> [dictionary - Python 2 **missing** method - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261126/python-2-missing-method)
>
> [Hidden features of Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#112286)

The last answer obtain 258 upvotes which frustrates me very much because I get no idea about it.
Could it be understood with basic knowledge of python?

Comment: If you write `c=Coordinate(); c['foo']` then `'foo'` is a missing key, and the `__missing__` method returns `'foo'`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted involves `__missing__()` in any way.  It only comes into play when you try to retrieve a dictionary key that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: It make sense now. @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do with `__missing__` here:

```
>>> Coordinate(x='6')
{'x': '6'}
>>> dict(x='6')
{'x': '6'}
```

This is just calling the dict initializer, because you inherit dict and you don't override `__init__`.

The effect of defining `__missing__` is shown below:

```
>>> c = Coordinate(x='6')
>>> c['new_key']
'new_key'  # returns the key, instead of raising KeyError
>>> c  # note: does not set it in the dict
{'x': '6'}
```

Comment: Yes, get it.`dict` is parent of class `Coordinate`,not a `parameter` to function `coordinate`.